# using a loop for creating multiple dummy variables

Tags: r, binary, boolean, stringr, dummy-variable

I am trying to create a loop to create dummy variable columns. My column `mydata$code` contains codes like `"AA1"` or `"AA2"`. I want to create an indivual column for each code, where the value of the row is 1 if the code is hit and 0 otherwise. I have multiple codes hence I don't want to do it all by hand. How would I fix my code below to achieve this?

```
x <- c("AA1","AA2","AA3","AA4")
for(i in 1:x){
  mydata$code_[i] <- as.integer(str_detect(mydata$code,"i"))
}
```

current

```
    ID Code 
1 9343  AA1    
2 8333  AA1   
3 6449  AA3
```

desired

```
    ID Code AA1 AA2 AA3 AA4
1 9343  AA1   1   0   0   0
2 8333  AA1   1   0   0   0
3 6449  AA3   0   0   1   0
```

Comment: Are you looking for `model.matrix(~0+x)`?

Comment: I am not doing regressions

Comment: I didn't say you are, try it with the posted vector. Or with another small vector.

Comment: that isnt' what im after

Comment: that creates the contrasts

Comment: Can you post expected output? There is also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952706/generate-a-dummy-variable/40343274) you could check out.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649443/how-to-one-hot-encode-several-categorical-variables-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539750/r-how-to-one-hot-encoding-a-single-column-while-keep-other-columns-still

Answer (score 2):

Could try to do something like this where you loop over the elements in `x` and then use an `ifelse` statement

```
x <- c("AA1", "AA2", "AA3", "AA4")


db <- data.frame(codes = sample(x, 10, TRUE))

db_new <- cbind(db, Reduce(cbind, lapply(x, function(i) ifelse(db$codes == i, 1, 0))))
```

If db is:

```
   codes
1    AA4
2    AA1
3    AA4
4    AA1
5    AA2
6    AA4
7    AA4
8    AA1
9    AA1
10   AA1
```

Then output becomes:

```
   codes init V2 V3 V4
1    AA4    0  0  0  1
2    AA1    1  0  0  0
3    AA4    0  0  0  1
4    AA1    1  0  0  0
5    AA2    0  1  0  0
6    AA4    0  0  0  1
7    AA4    0  0  0  1
8    AA1    1  0  0  0
9    AA1    1  0  0  0
10   AA1    1  0  0  0
```

EDIT:

EDIT:

It appears that your subscript is wrong. `db$code[j]` will take the `j`th element of the column `code` in `db`. So that will obviously not work. You could try this:

Assuming that you are using the same codes for all columns and that they are given in `x`:

```
x <- c("AA1", "AA2", "AA3", "AA4")
```

Furthermore, assume that all your code columns are in your `data.frame` and that this is the only data in your `data.frame`.

```
db <- data.frame(codes_1 = sample(x, 10, TRUE),
                 codes_2 = sample(x, 10, TRUE))
```

Then we can use the fact that the `data.frame` works like a list and can be passed through `lapply`.

```
db_list <- lapply(seq_along(db), function(i, x) {
  var <- db[[i]]
  var_name <- colnames(db[i])
  db_tmp <- cbind(db[i], Reduce(cbind, lapply(x, function(j) ifelse(var == j, 1, 0))))
  colnames(db_tmp) <- c(var_name, paste(var_name, x, sep = "_"))
  return(db_tmp)
  
}, x)
```

```
[[1]]
   codes_1 codes_1_AA1 codes_1_AA2 codes_1_AA3 codes_1_AA4
1      AA1           1           0           0           0
2      AA2           0           1           0           0
3      AA4           0           0           0           1
4      AA3           0           0           1           0
5      AA3           0           0           1           0
6      AA3           0           0           1           0
7      AA3           0           0           1           0
8      AA1           1           0           0           0
9      AA4           0           0           0           1
10     AA4           0           0           0           1

[[2]]
   codes_2 codes_2_AA1 codes_2_AA2 codes_2_AA3 codes_2_AA4
1      AA4           0           0           0           1
2      AA3           0           0           1           0
3      AA3           0           0           1           0
4      AA3           0           0           1           0
5      AA4           0           0           0           1
6      AA1           1           0           0           0
7      AA4           0           0           0           1
8      AA2           0           1           0           0
9      AA2           0           1           0           0
10     AA3           0           0           1           0
```

This gives you a list the length of the nubmer of columsn that you have, each with the desired matrix. If you want to get it all back into one, you can do this:

```
Reduce(cbind, db_list)
```

Comment: That seems to work fine. There are actually about 20 code fields to search from. They are `code_1,code_2,...,code_20`. Is there a way to loop through these?

Comment: `for (j in 1:20){
db_new<- cbind(db, Reduce(cbind, lapply(x, function(i) ifelse(db$code[j] == i, 1, 0))))
}`

Comment: That should work. Should then perhaps add a new column name to each before binding them to `db`. The easiest would be to append using the value of `j` or better the actual column name of the code field.

Comment: `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 19503, 0`

Comment: In your edit are the fields generic, I can't seem to get it running?

Comment: I just ran it in a clean R session and my edited example does run and should give the desired output. `db` needs to be a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 2):

Or simply

```
test_df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = code, values_fill = 0, values_fn = length, values_from = code)

# A tibble: 8 x 5
  ID      AA1   AA3   AA4   AA2
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 9348      1     0     0     0
2 8333      1     0     0     0
3 6449      0     1     0     0
4 8525      1     0     0     0
5 5306      0     0     1     0
6 1230      1     0     0     0
7 3039      0     0     0     1
8 2376      1     0     0     0
```

Thanks to @jared_mamrot for data

```
test_df <- data_frame("ID" = c("9348", "8333", "6449", "8525", "5306", "1230", "3039", "2376"),
                      "code" = c("AA1", "AA1", "AA3", "AA1", "AA4", "AA1", "AA2", "AA1"))
```

Comment: This can't handle blank codes

Comment: Means you also want a duplicate `code` column in output?

Answer (score 0):

Try `tidyr::pivot_wider()` and use your column for `names_from` argument.

If you want 0s instead of NANs in your result, use the argument `values_fill = 0`

You might need to play with the code by adding a variable of all 1s to your original df and use it for `values_from` arg, but I am not sure as the question is not complete.

```
Org_df %>% 
mutate( dummy_value = 1 ) %>% 
pivot_wider( id_cols = id, names_from = code, values_from = dummy_value, values_fill = 0 )
```

Comment: This is basically what I did - nice answer :)